# How do prevent whitespace from appearing in these bash variables?

Tags: bash, shell, ini

I'm reading in values from an .ini file, and sometimes may get trailing or leading whitespace.

How do I amend this first line to prevent that?

```
db=$(sed -n 's/.*DB_USERNAME *= *\([^ ]*.*\)/\1/p' < config.ini);
echo -"$db"-
```

Result;

```
-myinivar -
```

I need;

```
-myinivar-
```

Comment: Change your capture from `\([^ ]*.*\)` to `\([^ ]*\)`? Is there a purpose for the `.*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `.*` inside the capturing group (or the semicolon at the end of line):

```
db="$(sed -n 's/.*DB_USERNAME *= *\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' < config.ini)"
```

To elaborate:

1. `.*` matches anything at all
2. `DB_USERNAME` matches that literal string
3. `*` (a single space followed by an asterisk) matches any number of spaces
4. `=` matches that literal string
5. `*` (a single space followed by an asterisk) matches any number of spaces
6. `\(` starts the capturing group that is used for `\1` later

   1. `[^ ]` matches anything which is *not* a space character
   2. `*` repeats that zero or more times
7. `\)` ends the capturing group
8. `.*` matches anything at all

Therefore, the result will be all the characters after `DB_USERNAME =` and any number of spaces, up to the next space or end of line, whichever comes first.

Comment: I guess, the search part should be `.*DB_USERNAME *= *\([^ ]*\).*`, to remove any ` *` after the output interested.

Answer (score 2):

Use [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

```
echo "=${db% }="
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo` to trim whitespace:

```
db='myinivar '
echo -"$(echo $db)"-
-myinivar-
```

Comment: Don't do that! if `db` contains, e.g., a wildcard, you'll go through globbing. `echo` is not meant to be used this way.

Answer (score 1):

Use crudini which handles these ini file edge cases transparently

```
db=$(crudini --get config.ini '' DB_USERNAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of more than one trailing space, use %% which removes the longest matching pattern from the end of the string

`echo "=${db%% *}="`